# Как выводить игровой счёт на экран во время игрового процесса?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть некий класс защитника крепости. В этом класс есть метод увеличения счёта игрока и переменная score. При столкновении она увеличивается на +1. Как выводить и изменять этот счет на экране во время игрового процесса, чтобы этот счёт выводился слева и сверху?
Я использую `Canvas`

Comment: TextView       ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для размещения  какого то текста на канве необходимо использовать метод `drawText()` класса `Canvas` , при этом параметры текста(цвет , размер и тд.) задаются с помощью [методов](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#pubmethods) класса `Paint`:

например:

```
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   int x = 10;
   int y = 10;

   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   paint.setTextSize(35.0f); // значение типа float
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

   canvas.drawText("Some text here", x, y, paint); //x и y - позиция текста на канве
 }
```

Для того , чтобы выводить и изменять счет , вы можете написать отдельный метод основанный на написанном выше , например, `showScore(score);` который будет печатать текст с вашим счетом в заранее определенном месте ( левый верхний угол - это координаты x=0, y=0 )

более подробно о отображении текста на канве смотрите [этот](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/329-urok-149-risovanie-tekst.html) урок